# Where is the error near the word "from" in this SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you see the error in this MS SQL Server SELECT statement?

```
select clientname, our_date_finalized as our_dat, 
    specific_category as specific_c, 
    SUM(total_allowed) as total_allo, 
    SUM(total_charges) as total_char, 
    SUM(savings) as savings, 
    SUM(1) as claims 
Group By 1, 2, 3 
Order By 1, 2, 3 
from lob_activity.dbo.lob_activity where lob = 'Reprc'
```

The parser says it is returning an error near the keyword “from”.

Comment: SELECT/FROM/WHERE/GROUP BY/HAVING/ORDER BY

Comment: Can the close voter please explain how this question does not contain the specific problem code or explanation of the problem?

Comment: The order by has to go at the very end of the statement

Answer (score 5):

Your `from` was in the wrong place.

```
select 
      clientname
    , our_date_finalized as our_dat
    , specific_category as specific_c
    , sum(total_allowed) as total_allo
    , sum(total_charges) as total_char
    , sum(savings) as savings
    , sum(1) as claims
  from lob_activity.dbo.lob_activity
  where lob = 'reprc'
  group by clientname, our_date_finalized, specific_category
  order by 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Can you group by column numbers using MS SQL Server? (Only seems to work for me using the column names)

Comment: @sgmoore I'm just using the query from the question, but I went ahead and updated the answer with the column names.

Answer (score 2):

Because the From and where clauses must come before the Group By or order By

```
select clientname, our_date_finalized as our_dat, 
    specific_category as specific_c, 
    SUM(total_allowed) as total_allo, 
    SUM(total_charges) as total_char, 
    SUM(savings) as savings, 
    SUM(1) as claims 
from lob_activity.dbo.lob_activity 
where lob = 'Reprc'
Group By 1, 2, 3 
Order By 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this worked:

```
select clientname, our_date_finalized as our_dat, specific_category as specific_c, SUM(total_allowed) as total_allo, SUM(total_charges) as total_char, SUM(savings) as savings, SUM(1) as claims from lob_activity.dbo.lob_activity where lob = 'Reprc' Group By clientname, equian_date_finalized, specific_category Order By 1, 2, 3
```